# creating new lxc veth bridge on impish

Tags: networking, lxc

Following this excellent videos on Networing with lxc
The tutor uses Ubuntu 15.01
I use 20.04 impish
so when he discusses creating bridge in this [link](https://youtu.be/a0dzCzpdUfw?t=740) I am a bit stuck as impish uses Netplan.
I'll appreciate any help or redirected to a good resource - preferably a video to understand how to create new bridge on lxc.
Thank you

Comment: There's some confusing about Ubuntu releases. There never was a "15.01", there were 15.04 and 15.10 as usual. Ubuntu 20.04 is "focal". "impish" is Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: See https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges for excellent examples.

Comment: Thank you. I'll start reading and see what I can learn from this.